# WPF 4.0 Combo box Display Message When binding data is null

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have Two Combo boxes named **category** and **sub-category**. I want to display specific data in **sub-category** combo box based on **category** combo box  selection. But sometimes when I select some **category**, it doesn't have any value to show in **sub-category**. At that time I need to display an error message like **No Records Found**.

Is there some method to do so?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have binded category combobox with a db table and subcategory with another one.Sometimes it throws exception whenever the Sub-category combo box having null value. So I catch that exception.It show me an error when Im displaying a default text after the exception caught

Comment: where you want to display message?

Comment: Inside Sub-category combo box itself

Comment: I think you just need to fire a trigger that will enable the visibility of text block existing inside the controltemplate of combobox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Binding.TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) property. The value of this property is used as target value when the binding source value is null.